# Elasticsearch layered ordering

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to be able to return typeahead items in a certain order. For example, search for `Para` should return:

```
 Paracetamol

 Parafin

 LIQUID PARAFFIN

 ISOMETHEPTENE WITH PARACETAMOL
```

1) The suggestions that begin with the search term para should be ordered at the top and in alphabetical order

2) The rest of the items should appear below and also in alphabetical order

Is this possible with Elasticsearch?

### Update

What if I wanted the output to be like this:

```
 Paracetamol

 Parafin

 Amber Paraffin

 ISOMETHEPTENE WITH PARACETAMOL

 LIQUID PARAFFIN
```

So all the terms that contain the prefix are at the top and everything else in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my suggestion (also, you need to enable scripting):

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "standard",
            "lowercase",
            "ngram"
          ]
        },
        "search_ngram": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "ngram": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "index_analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "search_ngram",
          "index_options": "positions",
          "fields": {
            "not_analyzed_sorting": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
POST test/test/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"text":"Paracetamol"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"text":"Paracetamol xxx yyy zzz"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"text":"Parafin"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"text":"LIQUID PARAFFIN"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"text":"ISOMETHEPTENE WITH PARACETAMOL"}
```

---

```
GET /test/test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "Para"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": "termInfo=_index[field_to_search].get(term_to_search.toLowerCase(),_POSITIONS);if (termInfo) {for(pos in termInfo){return pos.position}};return 0;",
        "params": {
          "term_to_search": "Para",
          "field_to_search": "text"
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "text.not_analyzed_sorting": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

For your updated question, *even if I would have preferred to have another post*, use the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "text": "Para"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": "termInfo=_index[field_to_search].get(term_to_search.toLowerCase(),_POSITIONS);if (termInfo) {for(pos in termInfo){if (pos.position==0) return pos.position; else return java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE}};return java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE;",
        "params": {
          "term_to_search": "Para",
          "field_to_search": "text"
        },
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "text.not_analyzed_sorting": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @AndeiStefan I've made a slight amendment to my question wasn't sure if I should create a new question so just updated it instead.

Comment: @ImranAzad, I would have preferred another question. I updated my answer with a new query

Comment: sorry about I'll create another post, I think it's deserved, many thanks.

Comment: No, don't worry. Take a look at my updated response.

Comment: I'm curious 'return pos.position' will return the same position for terms that begin with the search term (0) so I'm unclear how the sort is able to sort alphabetically. How does it do it behind the scenes?

Comment: `if (pos.position==0) return pos.position; else return java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE` this means that if the position of the `term` that matched your query is the first one, then return that value, meaning `0`. If the position is not the first one then return a very big number (`java.lang.Integer.MAX_VALUE`). And the sorting in my query  it's done on two rules: the first is my script that returns `0` or `MAX_VALUE` and the 2nd is `text.not_analyzed_sorting` which is exactly your text. Whenever two `terms` are "the same" for the first sorting rule (the same `0` position or `same `MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: then the second sorting rule is used which the one based on your exact text, sorted alphabetically.

Comment: @AndeiStefan Ah I see now it's the second rule that applies alphabet sorting, many thanks!