# UNABLE TO ACCESS POS_OBJECT.endOffset using _OFFSETS

Tags: elasticsearch

When using _OFFSETS in my script and "with_positions_offsets" in my mappings I'm unable to get any values for POS_OBJECT.endOffset however if I use _OFFSETS and specify "index_options":"offsets" in my mappings file I am able to get at the values. Why is this the case? I was under the impression that "with_positions_offsets" would store positions and offsets in the index.

Comment: My mistake in [your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435670/elasticsearch-layered-ordering), I should have used `index_options` and not `term_vector`. Edited the post there. I was having the same false impression that `term_vector` was the one used in the scripts, but it's not, it's the `index_options` that makes the text scoring possible in scripts. More about the distinction between the two: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elasticsearch/3OsHn5w3H-E

Comment: @AndreiStefan Ah I see, many thanks Andrei! :-)